# Readjusting background image in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I tried to place an image in the background of the tkinter window, and added buttons but the image automatically places between two buttons(placed button on bottom left and bottom right) and image doesn't stretch horizontally.

How do we make the image stretch in background?
(I'm using tkinter in python  3.6.1)

Comment: You need to include a **minimal**, **complete** and **verifiable** example otherwise we can't help you. Refer to [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing this how your code looks like , change the image file to the file you want to use for your background.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")


lb = PhotoImage(file="Background image.png") # repalce with your file name
label = Label(root, image=lb)
label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

Button1 = Button(root, text="my button one").pack(side="left")
Button = Button(root, text="my button two").pack(side="right")

root.mainloop()
```

if you need additional help post in the comment box

Comment: This doesn't add an image as the background, it adds an image which has a size relative to the window of 0, meaning it's not visible. If you were trying to add an image which had the size of the background window it should be `relwidth=1, relheight=1`. This also won't account for changes to the size of the window or scaling of the image.